# clarify my understanding of (mod) in a function and explain the alternative solution

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

[image]

So im not sure if im understanding this correctly but it holds for each case in the table: is there a $1$ after the function output in $f(0)=16$ because $5\vert (16-1)$ ?

Also could someone help me understand the alternative solution

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. For $$a\equiv b\mod c $$ $a-b$ will be divisible by $c$. So $16\equiv 1\mod 5$ is true, as $5$ divides $16-1=15$

For the alternate solution, the first step is simply expanding the bracket to get $a^2+8a+16$

Now, because we're working modulo $5$, we can take out any multiple of $5$ from our equation because it will not influence whether the equation is a multiple of $5$ or not. Hence, we take out $5a$ and $15$, leaving us with $a^2+3a+1$

Comment: that cleared things up for me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$a=b(mod$  $ m)$  if $m|(a-b)$
So $16=1 (mod$  $ 5)$ because $5|(16-1).$

In-fact these are known as "modulo classes " that may have different representative .I hope it helps you